# Google Reader Like Web Application (SmartGWT) (GWT)

Tags: ajax, gwt, websocket, smartgwt

I need to write web aplication like google reader (using SmartGWT).

Instead of RSS feads I will show log files which updates in realtime. I think I can start a timer and ask server are there any new logs every minute. Is this the right way to do this?

Do I have to use WebSockets? Are they working in all the modern browsers?

Comment: You may also be interested in http://socket.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I can start a timer and ask server are there any new logs every minute. Is this the right way to do this?

Without using server push this is the way to go. You typically want to query the server with the timestamp of the last received log entry. This way can you only send the diff since the last pull.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ) for some more information on GWT and push (which is actually pull). Or check out [stream-hub](http://www.stream-hub.com) (and the pimped [stock watcher example](http://www.stream-hub.com/demo/gwt-comet-stock-table/gwt-stock-table-demo.html)) if you wanna go for server push.